# Variable value not getting printed in Detail band

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on a jasper report which uses following query:

```
select * from user_type
```

columns:

```
user_type 
visit_date
sessions
```

user_type have values either "New Visitor" or "returning Visitor".
To get count of sessions of "New Visitor" I am creating a variable as:

```
<variable name="new_visitor" class="java.lang.Long" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{user_type}.equals("New Visitor") ? $F{sessions} : 0]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

But when I print value of this variable in detail band or summary band its printing only zero.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: did u try setting initialValueExpression?